# Is there a way to select only partial matching and not the exact ones

Tags: r, string

I have two character vectors. The first one contains some references of natural disasters: "avalanche","flash flood","thunderstorm winds"...etc.
The second one with similar data but slightly different:"avalanche","flood","heat","winds" etc..... I am trying to find, not only the exact, but also the partial matching of the first one within the second one. So I thought I could do it separetely.

The first one is quite direct: match(dt_event,ref_event). Now I need also the "thunderstom winds" and"floash flood" to be considered as "flood" and "winds" from the ref_event, and thus get the indices as well instead of NAs. If there is a way to have both exact and partial matching in one command that would be better. Thanks in advance.

```
dt_event <- c("avalanche","flash flood","thunderstorm winds")  
ref_event <- c("avalanche","flood","winds")  
match(dt_event,ref_event)
```

1 NA NA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that two vectors are ordered and you want to compare element-wise:

```
dt_event[unlist(Map(grepl, ref_event, dt_event))]
```

or in a more general case:

```
dt_event[sapply(ref_event, function(x) which(grepl(x, dt_event)))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That brings both partial and exact match b-e-a-t-i-f-u-l-l-y. Any explanation please: the grepl function alone would return only the exact matching. What does the map function do please? The documentation is not that clear. Thank you again

Comment: It is important to note that this only does elementwise comparison of vectors. `grepl` does partial matching provided your reference vector is a pattern: `grepl("a", c("abc", "bc"))`. `Map` applies two lists to a function of two arguments.